# How to produce markdown chunk not to be interpreted?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I need to expose a **markdown syntax**, for figures, i.e. "! [caption] (imagepath)".

If you write it as-is, it will be ***interpreted and rendered*** by markdown.
Same appears to be true, if you generate the syntax from an R chunk.

What is the best way to achieve this result in a R markdown file ?

`r '![caption](imagepath)'`  # works but displays nothing

`r '! [caption] (imagepath)'`  # works, based on a visible hack as spaces are not so easy to capture for human eyes

Actual result with visual hack is "! [caption] (imagepath)". Perfect result should be the same without spaces and without markdown interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it in backticks:

```
`![caption](imagepath)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make a whole markdown chunk not to be interpreted by adding:

`eval = FALSE` to it.

so

`{r ,eval=FALSE}`
 `'![caption](imagepath)'`

creates the output:

> `[1] "![caption](imagepath)"`